# Unable to post requests to backend from Cloud front

Tags: amazon-cloudfront

I have the Cloud Front setup to allow POST to the backend server as follows

[image]

and behavior as

[image]

[image]

But I am getting

[image]

It looks like the request was not being routed to the backend, any idea?

Comment: A 405 HTTP code is for `Method not allowed`, are you sure you've saved the changes on the CloudFront to allow, at the very least, the `POST` method?

Comment: Yes, I was using Terraform to create the resources.

Comment: it appears you're matching with the default cache behaviour instead of the specific one you have created

Answer (score 0):

Actually,the mapping in CloudFront should just be /login as the frondend form has just the action="/login". And also, the origin domain needs to be a public domain that accessible from CloudFront otherwise it will not work